# zip and unzip in java

Tags: java, jar, zip, unzip

I know that it is an easy task, but after changing my code it stopped working and I can't get it back! I use two functions to zip and unzip, even though what it actually does is "jar" and "unjar", but that shouldn't make a huge difference

```
   public static void zipit(File[] infiles, JarOutputStream jos) throws Exception
   {
      zipit(infiles,"", jos);
   }

   public static void zipit(File[] infiles, String root, JarOutputStream jos) throws Exception
   {

      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

      for(int i=0; i<infiles.length; i++)
      {
         // recursive call for subfolders... temporary
         if(infiles[i].isDirectory())
         {
            zipit(infiles[i].listFiles(), infiles[i].getName() + "/", jos);
            continue;
         }

         // create string with absolute path
         String entryfile = root + infiles[i].getName();

         JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(entryfile);
         zos.putNextEntry(entry);

         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(infiles[i]);

         int count;
         while((count = fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
            zos.write(buffer, 0, count);
      }
   }

   public static void unzipit(File zipfile, File outputfolder) throws Exception
   {
      JarFile jar = new JarFile(zipfile);

      for(Enumeration entries = jar.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements(); )
      {
         JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();
         File unzipped = new File(outputfolder, entry.getName());
         if (entry.isDirectory() && !unzipped.exists())
         {
            unzipped.mkdirs();
            continue;
         }
         else if (!unzipped.getParentFile().exists())
            unzipped.getParentFile().mkdirs();

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(unzipped);
         InputStream in = jar.getInputStream(entry);

         byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
         int count;
         while((count = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
            fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
         fos.close();
      }
   }
```

Any help/suggestions?

The error occurs when creating the JarFile:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:114)
```

Comment: What did you change? Perhaps you should consider using source control.

Comment: What exactly does not work? "Stopped working" is not enough

Comment: I was only testing the unzip function, but when I try to unzip something previously zipped with the zip function, it spits out the error

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file)

Comment: after looking at your link, it does seem to be a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but it is generally good practice to close each zip entry after you finish writing.

See [`ZipOutputStream.closeEntry()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#closeEntry%28%29).

In the code that you show, the very last entry in the zip would not be closed.  You also don't show where you close the JarOutputStream itself.  This could be causing you to create invalid zip files, which would have errors when they are read back in using your other method.

Comment: that was my guess, but i tested it in main, and even when i close all streams and zip files it doesn't work

Comment: @omtinez, I'm glad you solved your problem.  If closing the stream was the answer, then the usual way to do things on StackOverflow is too accept the correct answer as the solution.  Reposting the code snippet with the 2 line change as a separate answer is not the way things are typically done.

Comment: thank you for your understanding, i make it look pretty obvious that i'm fairly new in stackoverflow but i will try to improve that

Answer (score 3):

Somehow I got it working, apparently it WAS stream-related... thanks for the help, everyone!

```
class zipper
{
     static byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

     public static void unzip(File zipfile, File outputfolder)  throws Exception
     {
         JarFile zip = new JarFile(zipfile);

         Enumeration entries = zip.entries();
         while(entries.hasMoreElements())
         {
             JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();
             File unzipped = new File(outputfolder,entry.getName());

             if (entry.isDirectory() && !unzipped.exists())
             {
                 unzipped.mkdirs();
                 continue;
             }
             else if (!unzipped.getParentFile().exists())
                 unzipped.getParentFile().mkdirs();

             InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(entry);
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(unzipped);

             int count;
             while((count = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
                 fos.write(buffer, 0, count);

             // clean up
             fos.close();
             in.close();
         }
   }

   public static void zip(File[] infiles, JarOutputStream jos) throws Exception
   {
       zip(infiles,"",jos);

       // clean up
       jos.flush();
       jos.close();
   }

   public static void zip(File[] infiles, String basefolder, JarOutputStream jos) throws Exception
   {
       for(int i=0; i<infiles.length; i++)
       {
           if(infiles[i].isDirectory())
           {
               // recursive call for directories
               zip(infiles[i].listFiles(), infiles[i].getName() + File.separator, jos);
               continue;
           }

           String filepath = basefolder + infiles[i].getName();
           JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(filepath);
           jos.putNextEntry(entry);

           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(infiles[i]); // get stream

           int count;
           while((count = fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
               jos.write(buffer, 0, count);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I needed to get to some sources stuffed in a jar. --dan