# Eclipse - error executable jar file

Tags: eclipse

When I use the eclipse function export - executable jar etc ...

I get a message when It's making the jar

JAR export finished with warning. See details ...

Details : Could not read JAR file '.classpath'. Reason : error in opening zip file.

I have no idea what this means and what I need to do to solve this ...

Anyone an idea?

thx all

Comment: This is just a warning.In the export untick the .classpath and .project and once the export is done, see if the jar can actually run

Comment: And where do you untick them?  I use export - executable jar .... the only thing I can change is the main class, what to do with the jar's in my project .. and where to put the file.  that's it ... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are packaging your application with the [Runnable Jar File](http://auralbits.blogspot.com/2010/10/automating-java-application-packaging.html), this message is usually associated with some kind of [permission issue on a `%TEMP%` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file/326308#326308).

[image: Runnable Jar file dialog]

Check also if the option to generate a script display the same behavior when executed.