# ZipException when unzipping file in Java

Tags: java, zip

I am totally fresh in handling zip file using Java,
and I have encountered a strange situation.

Here is the method I am using for unzip:

```
public void unzip(File zipFile, File rootDir) throws IOException
{
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
    Enumeration<ZipEntry> entries = (Enumeration<ZipEntry>) zip.entries();

    while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        java.io.File f = new java.io.File(rootDir, entry.getName());
        if (entry.isDirectory()) { // if its a directory, create it
            continue;
        }

        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        /*BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(entry)); // get the input stream
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(f));
        while (bis.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
            bos.write(bis.read());
        }
        bos.close();
        bis.close();*/

        InputStream is = zip.getInputStream(entry);
        OutputStream os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int r ;
        while ((r = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            os.write(buf, 0, r);
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
    }   
}
```

However, a IOException has been thrown and the message is:

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/30 01:58:05 | java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/30 01:58:05 |       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/30 01:58:05 |       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:127)

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/30 01:58:05 |       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:143)

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks a lot.

***Update:***

I am using Linux as a testing environment.
The permission for the unzip directory is drwxr-xr-x –

***Update 02:***

By adopting the suggestion from @heikkim,

I have just tried to use unzip commend in linux, trying to unzip my file manually. I have the following message:

Archive:  TMA_Template.zip
caution:  zipfile comment truncated
warning [TMA_Template.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
error [TMA_Template.zip]:  missing 6366880279 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [TMA_Template.zip]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)

Comment: related to file permission ?

Comment: Jan: I have created another zip file and tested, still the same exception.

Swagatika: I am not quite familiar with handling zip file using Java, my testing environment is Linux and I have checked with the permission, the parent directory shows me drwxr-xr-x

Comment: is there a causedBy in the stacktrace?

Comment: check this question, similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file

Comment: Is the Exception the same if you remove the file? I'm asking this because the file just might not found.

Comment: Have you verified that the file can not be inflated with some other program such as **gunzip**?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this method:

```
private void unzip() throws IOException {
    int BUFFER = 2048;
    BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
    BufferedInputStream is = null;
    ZipEntry entry;
    ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("latest.zip");
    Enumeration e = zipfile.entries();
    (new File(root)).mkdir();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
        //outText.setText(outText.getText() + "\nExtracting: " + entry);
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            (new File(root + entry.getName())).mkdir();
        } else {
            (new File(root + entry.getName())).createNewFile();
            is = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(root + entry.getName());
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((count = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, the exact same exception has been thrown.