# Eclipse generated war file is invalid in JBoss

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have an issue with Eclipse generated war files when deployed to JBoss. I have configured an instance of JBoss 5.1.0 in Eclipse and have Eclipse deploy to JBoss. When started, JBosss complains it can not read a zip file (I assume it is the war file since it doesn't tell me anything else). The error is like this:

```
13:27:08,824 ERROR [ProfileDeployAction] Failed to add deployment: test.war
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error determining structure: test.war
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WARStructure.determineStructure(WARStructure.java:248)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:196)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:221)
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1004)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:440)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:390)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:300)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.addDeployment(MainDeployerAdapter.java:86)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(AbstractExceptionHandler.java:39)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.helpers.NamesExceptionHandler.handleZipEntriesInitException(NamesExceptionHandler.java:63)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:626)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.checkIfModified(ZipEntryContext.java:773)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.getChild(ZipEntryContext.java:817)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.createChildHandler(ZipEntryHandler.java:191)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVirtualFileHandler.structuredFindChild(AbstractVirtualFileHandler.java:684)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getChild(ZipEntryHandler.java:165)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getChild(DelegatingHandler.java:107)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.AbstractVirtualFileHandler.structuredFindChild(AbstractVirtualFileHandler.java:689)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.getChild(ZipEntryHandler.java:165)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.DelegatingHandler.getChild(DelegatingHandler.java:107)
    at org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFile.getChild(VirtualFile.java:481)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.helpers.AbstractStructureDeployer.applyMetadataPaths(AbstractStructureDeployer.java:481)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.helpers.AbstractStructureDeployer.createContext(AbstractStructureDeployer.java:455)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WARStructure.determineStructure(WARStructure.java:204)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:143)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.ensureZipFile(ZipFileWrapper.java:175)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.acquire(ZipFileWrapper.java:245)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.initEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:484)
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.ensureEntries(ZipEntryContext.java:619)
    ... 38 more
```

I have examined the war file and it looks ok and surprisingly if I extract the war file and zip its content with 7zip, JBoss starts fine. I am puzzled as to how Eclipse creates a war file that is not readable by JBoss. The same war file works fine with Tomcat.

Has anyone seen this before? How can I fix this?

Comment: I would figure out what version of the JDK Eclipse is using, vs. what version JBoss is using. It looks like you need to determine what version of java.util.zip.* you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after debugging I figured out one of the library jar files had a zero size. The project for which the jar was zero sized was empty and eclipse produced a zero sized jar file for it (for whatever reason). I am not sure in what combination I could get the war file to deploy to jboss before but this was definitely the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue, as pointed out in another [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file), is that the JVM is attempting to unzip to a temp directory that it cannot write to.  Try to determine where it is trying to unzip to.

Answer (score 0):

May be its your web.xml file problem, i'm also face same kind of issue, After a lot of different tries, I was about to go down the road discussed another article about the web.xml and web-app 3.0. This got me to thinking and I checked out my web.xml. Sure enough, the following line was right there at the top.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

I changed over to a 2.5 web-app spec. Both the WAR and EAR would not deploy.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```