# new Lucee installation on Linux Mint 18.1; HTTP Status 500 - java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

Tags: java, lucee

Linux Mint 18.1
Apache/2.4.18
MySQL 5.7.16
PHP 7.0
PhpMyAdmin 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2
Lucee 5.1
Apache Tomcat/8.5.6

I just installed Lucee 5.1, using default installation parameters. When I view the Lucee admin web page -- http://127.0.0.1:8888/ -- I get an HTTP 500 error. The full error is given below. Why do you think there is an empty ZIP file? Has anyone else seen this error in Lucee? Thank you for any advice to resolve this.

best from Eric

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

type Exception report

message java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.initEngine(CFMLEngineFactory.java:387)
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.initEngineIfNecessary(CFMLEngineFactory.java:280)
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.getInstance(CFMLEngineFactory.java:176)
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.getInstance(CFMLEngineFactory.java:214)
    lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.init(CFMLServlet.java:44)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    mod_cfml.core.invoke(core.java:152)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    lucee.loader.osgi.BundleLoader.loadBundles(BundleLoader.java:62)
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.initEngine(CFMLEngineFactory.java:368)
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.initEngineIfNecessary(CFMLEngineFactory.java:280)
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.getInstance(CFMLEngineFactory.java:176)
    lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.getInstance(CFMLEngineFactory.java:214)
    lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.init(CFMLServlet.java:44)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    mod_cfml.core.invoke(core.java:152)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.6 logs.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file

Comment: Hi, Rafael,

Thank you for that link. I have read through it and have tried to form my next steps. I guess I will try to manually unzip and rezip a file -- but I am not sure which file, exactly, to unzip and rezip; nor am I sure where to locate this file. Can you give me a hint? Thank you very much for your time. Eric

Comment: I am not 100% sure because I don't program Java often or use lucee but I am guessing that it is the `lucee-5.x.x.jar` library that is corrupted. You can download the jar file [here](http://stable.lucee.org/download/?type=releases). Run a search on your system for your existing lucee jar file and replace it with the downloaded one. I suspect this to be the case because the lucee bundleloader was the last function that was called before handing execution back to java standard library. Make sure the versions line up too.

Comment: Also, are you installing lucee using the system package manager?

Comment: Hi, Rafael,

Unfortunately, Lucee is not in the repository, or package manager, for Linus Mint. I wish it were.

That link to the lucee.org downloads page is very helpful. I downloaded the lucee.jar file. Now I am searching for the lucee.jar file on my computer. Hmmm ... I cannot seem to find it. I am wondering if I should download the lucee installation file anew, and start over with Lucee.

Comment: are you behind a firewall by any chance? I tracked down the code and it seems like you need to update your `.lco` file. Try this [Update your LCO file](http://docs.lucee.org/guides/updating-lucee/update.html#firewall)

Comment: Dear Rafael, I am going to try this tonight. More soon. Thank you again! Eric

Comment: Dear Rafael,

I apologize; I seem to be stuck again. I have been working for a couple of days now on your latest (and very helpful) comment. I downloaded the latest LCO file. And I am following the instructions here:

http://docs.lucee.org/guides/updating-lucee/update.html#firewall

However, I am not able to figure out how to stop Lucee. The instructions say Stop Lucee; and I have been doing research to learn how to do that in Linux Mint 18.1.

Do you have any suggestions about how to stop Lucee? Later I will also need to start Lucee, as well.

Thank you again for your patient help.

Comment: lucee is a servlet that must be run by a servlet container like tomcat, jetty, glassfish etc. once you download and install lucee you'll need to start it with one of those containers. That should start an http server on your machine and you can navigate to the `http://localhost:<port>` in your browser. To stop lucee open your servlet container app and stop lucee and the opposite to start it

Comment: Dear Rafael, that is very useful information, and gives me a better idea of what is going on. I got it to work. I was beginning to question my entire installation of Linux Mint. So, from the beginning, I reinstalled everything -- Linux Mint 18.1; Apache, MySQL, and so on. Then I installed Lucee and .... it worked just fine. I'm looking forward to learning more about the Lucee CFML interpreter.

Thank you very much for your patient, clearly-stated help. I really appreciate your time. Wishing you the best.

Eric

Comment: glad you got it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I fit's not the main lucee...jar, it may be a partial download of an update. Check the files in /opt/lucee/tomcat/lucee-server/patches/ and see if they will unzip. Remove the ones that do not.