# Error in opening zip file: Opening of big zip files >2GB

Tags: java, android

When I try to create a `java.util.zip.ZipFile` I get a `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`. This exception only occurs when I try to open a large `ZipFile` (> 2GB). Is there a trick to open big zip files?

Later I need to extract single files from this zip and I doubt that the `ZipInputStream` is fast enough to extract the required files, since I need to run over all files.

Here is my StackTrace:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:162)
```

**Update:**
I found out that it works on my desktop computer and it works if I open the ZipFile as a JUnit-Test within Android Studio, too (Since JUnit-Tests are run on the local desktop computer and not on the android device). However, I could not get it working on the android device. I guess the reason is the android file system.

Comment: Possible Duplicate. Refer this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file]

Answer (score 1):

Key point to remember, especially if you are processing large zip archives is that, Java 6 only support zip file up to 2GB.

Java 7 supports zip64 mode, which can be used to process large zip file with size more than 2GB

Also using streams for big files is a good idea:

```
private static void readUsingZipInputStream() throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));
    final ZipInputStream is = new ZipInputStream(bis);

    try {
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = is.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.printf("File: %s Size %d  Modified on %TD %n", entry.getName(), entry.getSize(), new Date(entry.getTime()));
            extractEntry(entry, is);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to enable the zip64 mode and how is this possible?