# Can't deploy war after adding consul discovery

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, service-discovery

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot microservice after adding Consul as Discovery agent. the problem is after I added the maven dependancy and Spring annotation. Now the WAR file can't be deployed any more, the error message is the following:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
...
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@47bffd1]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) 
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
... 17 more
...
2-Dec-2018 12:23:38.846 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /xxxx/apache-tomcat-8.5.6_DEV_xxx-Input-Management/webapps/xxxx-Input-Management
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xxxx-Input-Management]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
```

My **pom.xml** is:

```
<!-- PARENT POM -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<!-- /PARENT POM -->

<!-- POM -->
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <!-- Dependencies -->

        <!-- Other Dependencies -->
        <!-- /Other Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- /Dependencies -->
<!-- /POM -->
```

The application work fine with this configuration in local (embedded tomcat) the service was registred but when i deploy it they crash and with without the Consul it work fine even in the server.

Other informations :
- Tomcat : 8.5.6
- Spring : 2.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Thank you @Josemy

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when your jar file is corrupted, make sure you jars are not corrupted.
Also try to clean your project/tomcat directory.

Check this out maybe it will point you in the right direction:
[java.util.zip.ZipException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file)

Comment: Thank you, i will check that