# Unable to deploy Saiku on Tomcat. Saiku gets stuck on the loading screen

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, saiku

I am using JDK 1.8, Apache Maven 3.6.0, Apache Tomcat 9 and Saiku 3. I just downloaded the latest code from Saiku Github Repo, made some changes, built it. After successful build, the '.war' files named 'saiku-ui-3.17.war' and 'saiku-webapp-3.17.war' are created inside 'Saiku-Server' folder. I renamed them to 'ROOT.war' and 'saiku.war' and tried to deploy it in Webapps of tomcat but the Saiku gets stuck in the login page with a error on TOMCAT console .

I've already tried using different versions of Apache Maven as well as Tomcat. I also tried deleting the '.m2' folder and rebuilding it.

The error in Tomcat console is :

```
02-May-2019 02:50:36.774 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.de
ployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Users\saunak.ranjitkar.adm\D
ownloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.19-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.19\webapps\saiku.war
]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:716)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:69
0)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1849)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineEx
ecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorS
ervice.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:36
6)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineEx
ecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorS
ervice.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.
java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
e.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize componen
t [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@694abbdc]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(Lifecy
cleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardR
oot.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardConte
xt.java:4797)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:4932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:713)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error
 in opening zip file
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.ini
tInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.
java:164)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.
java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.ini
tInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
        ... 45 more
'''
```

This is Chrome console error:

```
SaikuServer.js:107 Error performing GET on /saiku/rest/saiku/info
failure @ SaikuServer.js:107
```

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file looks like you have same issue - corrupted war file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file)

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak I tried unzipping it using Winrar and there are no errors. How can I confirm if my jar file is corrupted ?

Comment: try to rebuild your source code or may be try to use another servlet container for test purposes

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak Thanks for the info. I tried rebuilding it multiple times by deleting 'm2 repo' and it still doesn't work. Could there be any other options to make this work?

Comment: tomcat also print logs into multiple log files. check other log files. may be one of this logs files has more detailed error message